# Difference between functions for finding the optimal number of topics k (stm)

Tags: r, topic-modeling

The (amazing) `stm` package contains several functions for selecting the optimal number of topics in a topic model (*k*). Two of these functions are `searchK()` and `manyTopics()`.

Their descriptions in the documentation make them sound very similar: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/stm.pdf

`searchK()`: "With user-specified initialization, this function runs selectModel for **different user-specified topic numbers** and computes diagnostic properties for the returned model. These include exclusivity, semantic coherence, heldout likelihood, bound, lbound, and residual dispersion."

`manyTopics()`: "Works the same as selectModel [for which `searchK()` is a wrapper], except **user specifies a range of numbers of topics** that they want the model fitted for. For example, models with 5, 10, and 15 topics. Then, for each number of topics, selectModel is run multiple times."

From what I can tell, one difference might be that `manyTopics()` automatically picks the Pareto dominant model for *each* choice of *k*, whereas `searchK()` supposedly allows the user to pick between them given *k*. (However, I haven't seen any examples on how to actually do this, or why one would want to.)

Is there actually a difference, and if so, for what purpose should each function be used?